# ReactJS errors with rendering basic html component via variable

Tags: reactjs, require, fs

I am trying to pass a string for the jsx template name to a component that will be responsible for just rendering basic html only components with no interaction (we have a lot).

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';

export default class TemplateLoader extends React.Component {
  displayName = 'TemplateLoader'

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    var template = require('./static-templates/'+this.props.template+'.jsx');
    return template(this);
  }
}
```

and the output in the console is

```
    ./app/components/template-loader/static-templates/xxx.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/xxx/Sites/xxx/app/components/template-loader/static-templates/c017-top-phones-reasons.jsx Line 1: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <div class="xxx">
|
| </div>;
 @ ./app/components/template-loader/static-templates ^\.\/.*\.jsx$
```

If I switch it to

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import jsx from 'react-jsx';
import fs from 'fs';

export default class TemplateLoader extends React.Component {
  displayName = 'TemplateLoader'

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    var file = fs.readFileSync('./static-templates/'+this.props.template+'.jsx');
    var template = jsx.server(file, 'utf-8');
    return template(this);
  }
}
```

I get

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './static-templates/xxx.jsx'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
```

As commented below my set out is web pack, we're using Splash Pages for gocardless.com as a base. I've added html-loader, file-loader, css-loader.

My config for files has

```
node: {
  fs: "empty"
},
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html-loader" },
    { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
    { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader'] },
    { test: /\.json$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'json-loader' },
    { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader' },
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
  ],
},
```

Comment: Can you describe your build system a bit? It seems like you're using webpack without the appropriate loader for JSX. The command you're using to build and your config file would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Enable Compilation of .jsx files

Inform Webpack use babel-loader when it encounters files ending in `.jsx`. See https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#usage

So either add the following to your list of loaders:

```
'{ test: /\.jsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader'] },'
```

*or* modify your existing test so that it catches both `.js` and `.jsx`:

```
{ test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader'] },
             ^^
              \- add x? here
```

Here, the `?` mark operator in the test regular expression says "zero or one", so it captures both `.js` and `.jsx`.

### 2. Write your required modules according to CommonJS conventions

This won't work when you require it, because nothing is being exported. Everything in a CommonJS module is private to that module by default, you have to explicitly export whatever you want the caller of `require` to receive. So this will not work:

```
<div class="panel">

</div>;
```

Instead, export the JSX expression:

```
module.exports = <div className="panel">
    I am static template 2!
</div>;
```

See http://know.cujojs.com/tutorials/modules/authoring-cjs-modules

Remember that in JSX, you're not using straight HTML. You need to use `className` rather than `class`. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html for a list of other differences with "plain" HTML.

### 3. Make it work with React tooling

Now that you template is found, loaded, and compiled, it still won't render. You'll get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined` or something like it. Let's take a look at the JavaScript that is generated by the babel-loader, which transforms JSX into plain old JavaScript:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = React.createElement(  // <-- error here
  "div",
  { className: "panel" },
  "I am a static template 2!"
);
```

So the output of the JSX transform expects React to be in scope. This makes sense because JSX is just a convenience syntax for writing `React.createElement(...`. So finally, to make it all work together, your template needs to look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
// or var React = require('react');

module.exports = <div className="panel">
    I am a static template 2!
</div>
```

Caveat: I did not try to get this working with react-hot-loader directly, but it does work under webpack-dev-server, which I believe uses react-hot-loader. So this should work, but it it doesn't try removing react-hot-loader.

My working implementation looks like this. Note that I pass in the template as a prop rather than computing it within the component. I think this is more idiomatic React. Also this uses some new ES6 syntax for fun, but you're using babel so it should be okay. Not exactly what you are doing but close. One thing to note, it's probably better to call `require` once (in the constructor or in `componentDidMount`) rather than in the `render` function which can be called quite frequently.

```
var StaticTemplateComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return this.props.template;
    }
});

window.mountStaticComponent = (templateName, element) => {
    var templatePath = `./static-templates/${templateName}.jsx`;
    var template = require(templatePath);

    var staticTemplateComponent = React.createElement(StaticTemplateComponent, {template: template});
    React.render(staticTemplateComponent, element);
};
```

### 4. Automatically wrap your static templates in the required CommonJS

Out of scope for the question, and left as an exercise to the reader. It should be possible to write a custom webpack loader that automatically wraps your templates in the appropriate import/export statements. Bonus points for automatically transforming HTML5 into compliant JSX.

---

As far as why it doesn't work with `jsx.server`, I've never used it. Based on the error I would guess it's looking in the wrong directory for your files, so again, probably a configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks! I believe this is along the right path, however I encounter: 

ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/Sites/xxx/app/components/template-loader/static-templates/xxx.jsx:1:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at normalLoader (/Users/xxx/Sites/xxx/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:150:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .jsx] (/Users/xxx/Sites/xxx/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/r

I assume Babel is parsing the JSX thats to the new rule and its expecting React included in all modules?

Comment: Many thanks for this, this works, I'll look at taking on challenge 4 once I've got this implemented across the project :)